# How to only show important node's name on the networkx graph?

Tags: python, label, networkx

The graph looks messy and barely recognize anything.
I only want it to show the name of nodes with high centrality,
but I don't know how. I can only show all the names now.

[Graph：the result of the following codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjEUy.png)

> G_D=nx.Graph() G_D.add_edges_from(G5.edges(data=True))
>
> nx.draw(G_D,nx.spring_layout(G_D),node_size=[v * 10 for v in
>   df.iloc[:,0]],with_labels= True)

Answer (score 0):

`nx.draw` has an argument [labels](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx), which in combination with `with_labels=True` can draw only labels you want, only how you want.

> labels (dictionary, optional (default=None)) – Node labels in a
>   dictionary keyed by node of text labels

For example, you can pick nodes `'label'` parameter and draw labels for nodes that have 3 or more neighbours:

```
labels = {
    n: (G.nodes[n]['label']
        if len(list(nx.all_neighbors(G, n))) > 2
        else '')
    for n in G.nodes
}
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, labels=labels)
```

---

P.S. I don't recommend to use basic networkx drawing functional. There are many powerful visualization libraries better than networkx. Even [in networkx docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html) you can find the same opinion. One can use [Gephi](https://gephi.org/), [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) (with various libraries) or [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/) for really HUGE graphs.